# Does Maven remember its state so I can easily rerun last command?

Tags: java, maven, build, maven-3

I am using Maven multi module project. When I run maven and one of the modules fails I get the error messages and then the following line

```
After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
    mvn <goals> -rf :my.module.name
```

Does Maven hold any state? Is it possible to run

```
  mvn <goal> `start from where we left off`
```

The reason I ask is that some of my module names are quite long. I can copy from the cmd prompt but I'd just like a quicker / shorter command. Often saving a couple of seconds may not seem much but over the course of my maven usage it could save me a lot.

The question is

- does maven hold state?
- if so can I quickly rerun from where I left off?

Thanks

Comment: I'm not aware of such option. Maybe my builds don't fail that often and copy/paste from command line is enough? =)

Comment: It seems to me like the message from Maven already tells you how to do this. If your problem is overly long module names, then write a script or alias (or use a shell with command history search) to make it easier for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Maven Shell](http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/2010/03/23/intro-to-maven-shell/) to execute maven goals/phases in a pre-loaded shell environment, significantly reducing the build time.

Comment: do you know where I can download Maven Shell? All the links I find are dead... :(

Comment: You can download it from Maven repo at http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/sonatype/maven/shell/dist/mvnsh-assembly/1.0.1/mvnsh-assembly-1.0.1-bin.zip

Answer (score 1):

No, but you could go into the individual modules and build them - this is in essence what maven does, you just need to go through them in the correct order otherwise you might get confusing results (i.e old dependent-module builds etc). The reactor build summary shows you the module build order that maven will run through and is displayed at the start of the build.

In the end though you will always need to do a full build from the parent module in order to build your final artifact. And it's often easiest just to run from the top anyway.

Answer (score 0):

No - at least in my experience, Maven does not hold its state.  This is especially important if you are running `mvn package`.  Whereas running `mvn package` on a multi-module project will work fine (all modules will be able to use the produced artifact of a previous module), if the build is interrupted, resuming from your build mid-way will cause artifact not found errors when referring to previously successfully built modules.

Two ways around this.  Rebuild everything, or use `mvn install` to require maven to install to your local repo (if you are not ready to deploy).  In such a case, resuming your build will not fail as it will find the previously built modules in your local repo.

Just as a personal pet peeve, you need to know the module artifact name when using the `-rf` flag.  Maven will show you the display name, which may or may not be the artifact name.  `-rf` requires the artifact name.